# Jquery get index of an array of inputs of non-numeric indexes

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I have this inputs with non-numeric indexes with jQuery:

```
<input name="attributes['index1']" class="text_inputs" />
<input name="attributes['index2']" class="text_inputs" />
<input name="attributes['index3']" class="text_inputs" />
```

and this jquery code:

```
var attrs = new Array();
$.map( $('input.text_inputs'), function(obj, idx) {
    attrs['here_the_index_from_input'] = obj.value;
});
```

So I want to add each index from inputs to attrs array index.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `'here_the_index_from_input'` mean, for example, `'index1'`, `'index2'`, and `'index3'`?

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up a bunch of different concepts.

- You specifically said "non-numeric indices," which means you shouldn't use an array at all.
- If you're not going to use the array returned by `map`, use `each` instead.
- If you have a jQuery collection already, there's no need to use the `$.func` form. Just use `.func`.

  ```
  var attrs = {};
  $('input.text_inputs').each(function()
  {
      var $this = $(this),
          name = $this.prop('name'),
          val = $this.val();

      name = name.replace(/^attributes\['|'\]$/g, '');

      attrs[name] = val;
  });
  ```

I assumed that by `'here_the_index_from_input'` you mean, for example, `'index1'`, `'index2'`, and `'index3'`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/t2hX5/

Answer (score 0):

```
  var attrs = [];
  $.each($('input.text_inputs'), function(){
      attrs[$(this).attr('nameOfIndexAttribute')] = $(this).val();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (if i unerstood correctly what you want)

```
var attrs = {};
$.map( $('input.text_inputs'), function(obj, idx) {
    attrs[obj.name] = obj.value;
});
```

attrs is an associative array with the names of the input field as the key and the values of the input field as values.

EDIT - use an object as correctly stated in the comment, not an array

Comment: `var attrs = {};` or `var attrs = new Object();` ***Not*** `var attrs = new Array();`. Arrays are for numerical indices only. Just because you _can_ tack on ad-hoc properties doesn't mean you should.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the answer and keep that in mind!What i wanted to show was how to use obj.name to get the name of the input.